# UWP C++/CX change style programmatically?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

I need to create a lot of buttons programmatically for my app.

I can do that, but I'd like to change their style to `ButtonRevealStyle`.
I searched for answers on internet, but they all concerned C#, and I can't get it to work with this, which may look like a C++ equivalent `button->Style = (Windows::UI::Xaml::Style^)Application::Current->Resources["ButtonRevealStyle"];`

So my question is, how can I set the style of a button programmatically in UWP with C++/CX ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use C++/CLI in a UWP project.  It does tend to be confused with the C++/CX extension syntax.  So google "c++/cx casting" to find the docs.

Comment: ty i rectified it

Comment: The FolderEnumeration sample [has an example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/FolderEnumeration/cpp/Scenario2.xaml.cpp#L97).

Comment: ty that's what i needed